# DataGridview.ContainsFocus returning wrong

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I'm using a winform DataGridView for data entry.  The problem is that when my user has entered a row but not clicked off it, that row isn't getting saved to the grid's datasource (a datatable in memory).  So, when my user submits the form, I want to detect if the DataGridview has focus, and simulate a keypress (tab?) or set the focus to a different control or do some other operation to save the current row without changing the data.

`DataGridView.ContainsFocus` is always returning false, as is `DataGridView.Focused`.  Is there another property i should be using?  How should I save this row of data?

EDIT: See this question [Trouble using DataGridViewComboboxColumn for input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9280570/456532) for how I'm creating the DataTable and binding it to the datagridview.  And [datagridview not allowing user to delete row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9488733/456532) to see another issue I had with this same datagrid.

Comment: If they are actually clicking a submit button, then focus has already left the grid. That's why Grid.Focused is false. There must be another reason that the changes aren't being committed to the datasource.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman -Ok, what should I look for?

Comment: Could you give a little bit more detail on the workflow here. You say that users have not clicked off a row, yet the save is being triggered. What is triggering that? I've hit similar things in the past but a long time ago so the details are fuzzy. As always some code would really help.

Comment: @DavidHall -I'm not sure what code to include here, my partial class is over 1,000 lines.  The "save" is just the user clicking on a Submit button which grabs the values from all the controls and passes them to my database code.  The user has typed something into the datagridview, but that row has not yet been committed.  I'm trying to save them from themselves, because this row is simply not getting saved, and there is no error message.  I'm not even sure how I could make an error message on this.

Comment: So do you have a binding source, or a datatable? Where are you getting the data to save? As Igby rightly says, clicking on the Submit button will cause the grid to lose focus which in normal cases should cause the row to commit. Does this work if the user tabs off the grid? As I said, I've encountered a similar problem but it was over two years ago at my last job so I can't recall the exact cause or fix. If you give enough code to reproduce it should be easy to fix.

Comment: @DavidHall -Bound to a DataTable.  If the user tabs to another control, it does work just as I want it to.  In the submit code I grab the datatable and pass it to another method to handle the transmission to the database.  See edits above for code.

Comment: I think you will need to break this down to the simplest example that shows the problem. Without that it is too hard to help. All I remember from my similar problem was that in the grid I was both periodically autosaving and that I had events on form closing. But for myself I was using a binding source a custom objects. One thing to look at is the EndEdit method on the grid. But I really think you will find the solution but starting with a simple grid the doesn't show the problem and then working up from there.

Comment: @DavidHall -I see no "EndEdit" event for my grid.

Comment: @DavidHall -If you take the attached example with the Lord of the Rings address data, and add a button to the form you can set a breakpoint in the buttons click handler and you'll see the problem.  I don't know how to simplify the grid more than that.

Comment: You'll need to provide some code - I've taken that example in a fresh project and added a button to submit - everything appears fine. The only thing I changed is that I moved the DataTable to class level scope - have you done that?

Comment: Create a BindingSource which is then used as the data source for the datagridview. Assign the datatable as the datasource for the binding source. Call the BindingSource.EndEdit() method before trying to save.

Comment: @sga101 - Can you post as an answer and expand?  I'm using something like `DataGridView.DataSource = DataTable`.  I've never explicity used a binding source, what do you mean?

Comment: I see no ContainsFocus http://i.imgur.com/yHT2o4b.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows forms controls can be connected directly to data sources, but are designed to be used with a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158145.aspx) control. This is used to marshall input from form controls to and from a data source.

It is a component which you can drag onto your form in the designer, and then you can set it as the data source for your datagridview control.

Once it is on the form, you can use the designer to set it as the datasource for your datagridview. Then you can use an event handler, for example, the form load event handler to provide a datatable as the data source for the binding source.

The binding source provides you with much finer control over how and when data is transferred from the form controls to the underlying data sources. Simply using the Binding Source may fix your problem. If not, then calling the EndEdit method on the binding source before attempting to save the data should cause any outstanding edits to be written to the datatable.

For a simple example, create a new Windows forms project. To the form, add a datagridview called "datagridview1", a BindingSource with the name peopleBinding source, and a command button called saveButton. Set the datasource for gridview1 to be peopleBindingSource.

Add event handlers for form.Load and saveButton.Click as follows:

```
   public DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        t.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
        t.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
        t.Rows.Add("Joe","Bloggs");
        t.Rows.Add("Fred","Bloggs");
        return t;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        DataTable people = GetData();
        peopleBindingSource.DataSource = people;

    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable t = peopleBindingSource.DataSource as DataTable;
    }
```

Run the application, and you should find that if you inspect the data table in SaveButton_Click that any changes you have made to the data are persisted.

If you prefer Visual Studio to write all the code for you:

1. Add a new Data source using the "Add data source..." wizard.
2. From the Data sources window, drag a table onto your form.

Visual studio will add the necessary DataGridView, BindingSource, etc and wire them all up for you. You can then inspect the code to see how it all fits together.

Comment: -Great explanation!  But, being stubborn as I am, I found a way to do this without changing my setup.  All I did was use your concepts and called this code in the submit button handler: `            if (gridDowntime.IsCurrentRowDirty)
            {
                gridDowntime.BindingContext[downtimeEntries].EndCurrentEdit();
            }
`